# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lamqpcpp

Tags: c++, docker, ubuntu, amqp

I'm trying to install [amqpcpp](https://github.com/akalend/amqpcpp) a rabbitmq client for c++ as part of the steps for building my c++ application. I cloned the repo and put the folder in the projects directory.

The dockerfile I'm using for the build:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Set environment variables
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update and install required packages 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    g++ \
    cmake \
    make \
    libpthread-stubs0-dev \
    git \ 
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ninja-build && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
# Create a directory for the app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy your CMake project files into the container
COPY . .

RUN cd /app

# # cd amqpcpp and build amqpcpp
RUN cd amqpcpp \
    && mkdir build && cd build \
    && cmake .. && cmake --build . --target install  && make && make install

RUN cd /app 

WORKDIR /app/build

RUN cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. && \
    cmake --build . --parallel 8

ENTRYPOINT [ "./app/build/exchange_main" ]
```

When I try to build the image. Everything works fine until the final build for the whole application. The amqpcpp build stage was successfull.

My cmakefiles.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(MatchingEngine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic")
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)


set(COMMON_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common)
set(RABBITMQ_C_SOURCE_DIR ${COMMON_DIR}/rabbitmq-c-0.13.0)
# set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/amqpcpp)

# Include directories for RabbitMQ-C headers

include_directories(${RABBITMQ_C_SOURCE_DIR}/librabbitmq)


add_subdirectory(common)
add_subdirectory(exchange)

list(APPEND LIBS libcommon)
list(APPEND LIBS libexchange)
list(APPEND LIBS pthread)
list(APPEND LIBS amqpcpp)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/exchange)

# Specify the directory where amqpcpp library is located
add_executable(exchange_main exchange/exchange_main.cpp)
# target_include_directories(exchange_main PRIVATE /usr/local/include)
target_link_libraries(exchange_main PUBLIC ${LIBS})
```

The full error i get is:

```
#0 2.570 /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/exchange_main.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
#0 2.576 g++  -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -O3 -DNDEBUG  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/exchange_main.dir/exchange/exchange_main.cpp.o  -o exchange_main  common/liblibcommon.a exchange/liblibexchange.a -lpthread -lamqpcpp 
#0 2.598 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lamqpcpp
#0 2.598 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
#0 2.600 make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/exchange_main.dir/build.make:89: exchange_main] Error 1
#0 2.600 make[2]: Leaving directory '/app/build'
#0 2.600 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:121: CMakeFiles/exchange_main.dir/all] Error 2
```

Comment: If you cloned the repo, you probably just have the sources available.  Did you actually compile that library before trying to link to it?

Comment: you try to link to RABBITMQ sourced and libs but where are they coming from?  your makefile doesnt even add headers for amqcpp just added it to link libraries.   Post the actual error you you are getting.

Comment: @UpAndAdam I just updated the post with the error. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @StephenNewell yes i did that in the docker file

RUN cd amqpcpp \
    && mkdir build && cd build \
    && cmake .. && cmake --build . --target install  && make && make install

Comment: If `ld` cannot find a library, then it's not there. It may be somewhere else, but `ld` won't look everywhere, only in the places you tell it to look. You **must** know where the library is and you **must** know where you tell `ld` to find it.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI how do I direct ld to where to look? I built the amqpcpp from source and from the make file, I think it's in the /usr/local/lib
The makefile
```
install:
 cp $(LIBSO) /usr/lib
 ldconfig
 cp include/* /usr/include/
```

Comment: Then look in /usr/local/lib and verify that it's there.